# An explicit realization of the similarity of the transpose of a matrix in function field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $K=\mathbb{F}(a,b,c,d)$ be the field of rational functions in four variables over a field $\mathbb{F}$. The matrix

$$ A=\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\       c & d \      \end{array} } \right)$$ over $K$ is conjugate to its transpose. Hence there exists an invertible matrix $P$ over $K$ such that $A^t=PAP^{-1}$. What is an explicit formula for $P$, in terms of $a,b,c,d$ ? Can we choose $P$ to have polynomial entries in $a,b,c,d$ ?

Comment: If $P$ works, then any scalar times $P$ will also work. So can't you just multiply $P$ with the product of the denominators?

Comment: Solve the linear equation $M^tP-PM = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**An example of $P$**

We may take 
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{a-d}b & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Then 
$$
PA=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{a(a-d)}b + c & a \\ a & b\end{pmatrix}=A^TP, 
$$
and $P$ is nonsingular.

**Polynomial Entries**

As suggested by @Jyrki Lahtonen's comment, it is possible to choose $P$ to have polynomial entries by multiplying $b$. If $$
P=\begin{pmatrix} a-d & b\\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Then we have 
$$
PA=\begin{pmatrix} a(a-d) + bc & ab\\ ab & b^2\end{pmatrix}=A^TP. 
$$